# How to store records as array in cakePHP with specific fields only?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have settings table, I want to store the records as an array like bellow

```
#   Field Name      
1   id              int(11)
2   setting_name    varchar(75)
3   value           text
```

The code in Controller is like bellow

```
$settings = $this->Settings->find('all');
```

I can do `foreach($settings)` and store it as an array like bellow, so, I can access it like .

```
$settings = array(
    1 => 'Value 1',
    2 => 'Value 2',
    3 => 'Value 3'
)
```

Is there any other way to do it without the `foreach()`?

Comment: Yes, but what's your use-case, and why does that use-case need to be without foreach?

Comment: @JonStirling I am a beginner of CakePHP so I want to know is there any functionality inbuild in CakePHP?

Comment: There is tons of functionality in CakePHP, but without knowing what problem you're actually trying to solve, we can't hope to give you useful suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Dear @GregSchmidt I want to use settings in my .ctp files, like <?=$settings[1]?> so it will show the value of record 1(primary key).

I have stored many details in settings table like contact email, phone number, social links, site name, etc etc in settings table, and i want to use them in .ctp files where ever its need.

I can make a $settings array with foreach, its working, no issues, but only thing i want to know is there any functions to do $settings array without foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$settings = $this->Settings->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'setting_name',
    'valueField' => 'value',
])->toArray();
```

Then you'll be able to reference for example `$settings['contact_email']` in your template.